# How in typescript check if substring match one of in list of strings

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's consider example

```js
type Routes = 'first' | 'second';

type BeforeSign = //...

const handleRoute = (route: BeforeSign<Routes, '#'>) => route;

handleRoute('first');
handleRoute('first#additional');
handleRoute('first#random');
handleRoute('second#example');

// @ts-expect-error
handleRoute('third');
// @ts-expect-error
handleRoute('third#nope');
```

How to write `BeforeSign` generic type to make all `handleRoute` calls without error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *template literal type* to concatenate the string literal together.

```
type BeforeSign<R extends string, D extends string> = R | `${R}${D}${string}` 

const handleRoute = (route: BeforeSign<Routes, '#'>) => route;
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BAzlAvFA5AMwJYBOKwWUAPtihAMZwB2AJlgNwBQrokUAQhDnAQgBlPAHM6AHhhQIAD2SM0xAnjqiANFAAiM+REVRlq0QD4MsclAAGAEgDeMAL72tzu0bWOrUdrTrEoAAsAQ0YAGwh4JGhMAAoCRGQALh4+AWExSSjkFE0sAGIsEwBKDDME6LZWEPDIxIhY3EJiLGK2GoYI7IamomB84IYGPGA8emCw1vbQzrroxvw+-IIZuABbKeqZrvrGqj8GfLlgtbAIzdYAekuoAAFgFABaOUhqYGeCBIIt2u7G4EChCYbSuN3uTxeNHeEE+Ah+sz+WABQPydDgkCmQA)